# Streaming with Druid, Kafka, Superset

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, apache-nifi, druid, data-stream

I am testing data streaming by using Kafka, Druid and SuperSet.

I am at the point where I have some data in Druid (see 1. picutre).

After that I am able to generate Druid datasource in Superset by option "Refresh Druid metadata" (see 2.pic)
Problem is when I wanna querie a data, I am getting this error message:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/superset/viz.py", line 329, in get_df_payload
    df = self.get_df(query_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/superset/viz.py", line 142, in get_df
    self.results = self.datasource.query(query_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/superset/connectors/druid/models.py", line 1238, in query
    client=client, query_obj=query_obj, phase=2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/superset/connectors/druid/models.py", line 959, in get_query_str
    return self.run_query(client=client, phase=phase, **query_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/superset/connectors/druid/models.py", line 1126, in run_query
    client.timeseries(**qry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydruid/client.py", line 167, in timeseries
    return self._post(query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydruid/client.py", line 484, in _post
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1244, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

And also see 3. pic

Any idea what can be a problem?

I am feeding Kafka thru the NiFi and then I have kafka source hooked to the druid target in SAM.

Thank you!

1. picutre
   [image: 1. picutre]
2. picutre
   [image]
3. picutre
   [image]
4. no data in superset
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, 
problem was that broker host was not defined in cluster configuration in super set UI.
I set it up to value: *localhost* 
and now it's up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Superset got a problem to connect to your Broker-Node. Check your cluster health. Especially the Broker- and Coordinator Node logs.

Comment: Thank! Superset might not be seted up correctly, @Stephan do you know where are the setting files? I do not have Superset in Ambari.

Comment: We use this Dockerimage for superset:

https://hub.docker.com/r/amancevice/superset/

in the /etc/superset/superset_config.py you can change settings related to superset itself.

Settings regarding the connection to druid you can set within the superset UI under Sources --> Druid Clusters. On the picture I can see that the connection to the coordinator node is working because superset is listing the datasources. What you can try is make a query via superset and check the logs of all Druid-Nodes. If you find something strange post it here

Comment: thank you!
I did not manage to solve this problem yet. Still at same point.
But when I am querying data thru the console it shows a data.

curl -L -H'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST --data-binary @quickstart/wikiticker-top-pages.json http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/?pretty
I added new picture to the post 4. no data in superset.
Do you know where to set up broker URL in superset? It might be problem.

Comment: If i run superset refresh_druid from CMD i got a same error as above, URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>